# How do I implement this after_create in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have two models - `Membership` and `Connection`.

On my `Membership` model, I have this `after_create` callback:

```
after_create :setup_connection, unless: Proc.new { self.connection_exists }

  def connection_exists
    Connection.where("invited_user_id = :user_a_id AND inviter_user_id = :user_b_id OR invited_user_id = :user_b_id AND inviter_user_id = :user_a_id", user_a_id: self.inviter.try(:id), user_b_id: self.invited.try(:id)).exists?
  end

  def setup_connection
    self.create_inviter_connection!(times_sent: 0, request_status: 0, inviter_user: self.inviter)
  end
```

This is my Membership Factory, where I tried to implement the `after_create`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :membership do
    family_tree
    association :inviter, factory: :user
    association :invited, factory: :user
    relation { Faker::Lorem.word }
    member

    after(:create) do |membership, evaluator|
      unless membership.connection_exists
        create(:connection, times_sent: 0, request_status: 0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But that just caused all of my tests to fail. I am not sure if it even works, because I can't test it properly. It takes FOREVER to run too.

This is my Connection Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :connection do
    association :invited_membership, factory: :membership
    association :inviter_membership, factory: :membership
    association :invited_user, factory: :user
    association :inviter_user, factory: :user
    sent_at { Faker::Time.backward(7, :evening) }
    responded_at { Faker::Time.forward(21, :morning) }
    send_limit 5
    times_sent 1
    removed_at { Time.now }
  end
end
```

Without that `after_create`, this is the summary of my test suite in this file:

```
Finished in 2.85 seconds (files took 4.88 seconds to load)
21 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

This is the summary with just that `after_create` added:

```
Finished in 3 minutes 29 seconds (files took 5.16 seconds to load)
21 examples, 20 failures, 1 pending
```

So clearly this doesn't work for what I need.

Thoughts on how I might better implement this?

Comment: You do not have to implement after create inside FactoryGirl, it will use after create from the `Membership` model, when the object instance is created, it will call the callback after_create

Comment: @Nermin Well it seems like it actually isn't. That's why I am thinking about this. Or rather, when I say it isn't, meaning if I create two `membership` records that should share 1 connection it is creating 2 connection records rather than just 1. So something funky is happening...I assumed that the callback wasn't being called.

Comment: Are you using `build(: membership)` or `create(:membership)` in your specs ? As @Nermin said, the `after_create` callback from the model should be called. Then the problem might be in the callback itself, and the factory should not be responsible to re implement an after create callback IMO

Comment: Hmm, I would say that your domain model is probably more complicated than necessary.  Member already works like a m2m join table between users. If you really need to have Connection for some reason then add a direct relation between Member and Connection.

Comment: Okay, here's a potentially stupid question.   `connection` is already a method on ActiveRecord objects.  Are you overriding it when an association method which is preventing the model from connecting to the database?

Comment: @prater `connection` is only a method on AR model classes, not on the instances themselves.